# Вывести значение title с id 1

Tags: php, mysql

В PHP и SQL еще зеленый, прошу помощи. Нужно вывести значение title у которого id = 1, подскажите как это сделать

```
$cardTitle = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT title FROM `products`");
mysqli_query ($db, 'set character_set_results = "UTF-8"');
?>
```

```html
<div class="scard">
            <div class="scardImage">
                <img src="assets/img/i1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <?php 
            while ( $title = $cardTitle->fetch_array() ) 
            { 
                ?>
            <h5 class="scardTitle"><?php echo $title['title']; ?></h5>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <p class="scardDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Excepturi architecto
                maiores impedit</p>
            <button class="buyBtn">Купить</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: может тогда начать хотя бы с пары вводных статей по SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вообще не нужен PHP, всё делается через один простой SQL запрос:

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE id= 1`

Если переводить, то звучит так:

Вывести всё из таблицы product, где id = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $cardTitle = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT title FROM products WHERE id = 1"); ?>

<div class="scard">
    <div class="scardImage">
        <img src="assets/img/i1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <?php while ($result = $cardTitle->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <h5 class="scardTitle"><?= $result['title']; ?></h5>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <p class="scardDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Excepturi architecto
        maiores impedit</p>
    <button class="buyBtn">Купить</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('HOST_DB', 'USER_DB', 'PASS_DB', 'NAME_DB'); // параметры подключения
$sql = "SELECT `title`
FROM `product`
WHERE `id`= '1';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

?>

<div class="scard">
            <div class="scardImage">
                <img src="assets/img/i1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <?php 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {   
            echo "<h5 class='scardTitle'>{$row['title']}</h5>";                
            }
            ?>
            <p class="scardDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Excepturi architecto
                maiores impedit</p>
            <button class="buyBtn">Купить</button>
        </div>
```